# Configure a group to change date via GUI without admin privileges

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, visudo

On Ubuntu 16.04, I would like to create a group of users, named "group_1", without admin privileges who would be able to change the date.

To do so, I use the command `visudo` and add the line :

```
group_1 ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/date
```

Each user of "group_1" is now able to change the date using the CLI:

```
date -s "Aug 01 01"
```

I would like to know how to configure Ubuntu to let the group of users change the date using the GNOME interface (GUI)?

Comment: Why the need for changing the date? Set it properly once and keep it precise using NTP. If you need false dates (e.g. for debugging), take a look at faketime (and perhaps other similar pieces of software). Randomly adjusting the system date backwards might have undesired consequences.

Comment: The device shall not be connected to any network: it's a standalone workstation.
The choice does not depend on me.

Answer (score 0):

The command to launch the datetime settings GUI with unity is:

```
unity-control-center datetime
```

Do not allow this command in the /etc/sudoers file because it can be used to create an admin user